# Android in app purchase fee

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

On iPhone in app purchase will take 30% of money you made. Is it the same for Android?

Comment: “Fortune is on the side of the strong.”
                                  -some mafia i don't know.-

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play Store policies, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 30%.

> For applications and all in-app products that you choose to sell on
>   Google Play, the transaction fee is equivalent to 30% of the price.
>   You receive 70% of the payment and the remaining 30% goes to the
>   distribution partner and operating fees.

[Source.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. I though only apply does that.